# Why is the wrong row being copied and pasted

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA

I am trying to loop through a table and copy the row containing a name.  When I run the code, the output is the row below the one I want.

```
Sub tblcopypast()

Dim Name As String
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
Name = ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Value
lastrow = tbl.ListRows.Count

For i = 1 To lastrow
    If tbl.Range(i, 1) = Name Then
    tbl.ListRows(i).Range.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("E5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `tbl.Range` includes the headers but `tbl.ListRows` does not

Comment: You should be able to fix this with `Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").databodyrange` which excludes the header row.

Comment: Your answers helped me fix the issues.  Thank you

Comment: Note that row counting variables **must** be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle: `Dim lastrow As Long`. I recommend [always to use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) in VBA since there is no benefit in `Integer` at all.

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54846091/vba-copying-from-table-and-pasting-to-create-list